# Bulk create and ignore unique in Django

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models, django-queryset

I am inserting many rows from one database to another database.

Right now I am checking if the object already exists with `get_or_create` but it makes many queries.

Can I use `bulk_create` and just passing through those rows that already exists in the database?

Is there other options to copy from one database to another database instead of looping through each object?

Comment: Is it possible for you to use the ```loaddata``` command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture

Comment: Why don't you use south (or the build in functionality) to perform data migrations?

Comment: I can't use the command. The end user has to synchronize the database by themselves often so the process has to be done fast.